# How can I retrieve my action parameters from controller action into Knockout VM

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

This is my controller action...

```
    // GET: ex: /Question/Details/5?project=1
    public ActionResult Details(int? project, int? questionId)
    {
      ...
    }
```

This is my Knockout VM:

```
    // Get some other info about question
    $(document).ready(function () {
            getSomeOtherInfo(<need to pass question id here>, <need to pass project id here>);
    });
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a strongly typed ViewModel for Details, you can add the two properties into the view model, then in the view provide the values to JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    getSomeOtherInfo(@(Model.project), @(Model.questionId));
});
```

If you are not using a strongly typed ViewModel, you can use the ViewBag

Comment: Thanks Queti, I tried your option.  

When I use 
getSomeOtherInfo(@(Model.project), @(Model.questionId));
I get an error "invalid character '@'"

and when I use 
getSomeOtherInfo(Model.project, Model.questionId);
I get an error 'Model' is undefined.

I understand I must be wrong somewhere in implementing your help, but where?

Comment: If you are using Razor view engine, then the @(Model.project) would work. If you are not, then you would do <%= Model.project %>

Comment: Found the answer why didn't it work for me.  I was writing it in my js file.  Below link explains in detail.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626662/access-a-model-property-in-a-javascript-file