# T4MVC using with external javascript files

Tags: t4mvc, chirpy

Is it possible to use T4MVC in an external js file?

I include a js file in my cshtml file

and in MyScript.js i have the following in a function

@Url.Action(MVC.MyController.MyAction())

but it never get compiled to its Action name (thought that runat server would do that trick but it didn't)

what am i missing?  I am also using chirpy if there is something that it can do to help...

thanks

Answer (score 3):

[T4MvcJs](http://nuget.org/packages/T4MvcJs) will help you handle that case.
It generates a .js file which you can use in your external js-scripts.

Using it is a lot like T4Mvc: *MvcActions.User.Index()* will give you "/user/index".

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a general MVC question than T4MVC. T4MVC simplifies how you call @Url.Action, but whether you use T4MVC or not, you won't be able to have server code in a plain .js file.

However, there are some solutions around, like [Using Inline C# inside Javascript File in MVC Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045451/using-inline-c-sharp-inside-javascript-file-in-mvc-framework)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will wait for you/MS to come up with a solution in the future...  also T4MVC is very nice and should be part of VS in the next release as well as the chirpy functionality to compile/compress .less/.css/.js files.